# How to set background image width as edge to edge

Tags: css, html

I am trying to make parallax scrolling and everything's working fine.
But what I want is that the background images use complete width of the page (as in edge-to-edge) but there is a little margin left on both sides of the background.

Here is my code:

```css
.container{
 max-width: 100%;
 margin: 0 auto;
 background: aqua;
 font-size: 24px;
 padding: 25px;
}
.parallax{
 width: 100%;
 background: url('Baradari.jpg') no-repeat center;
 background-size: cover;
 background-attachment: fixed;
 height: 500px;
}
.parallax2{
 width: 100%;
 background: url('rumi-darwaza.jpg') no-repeat center;
 background-size: cover;
 background-attachment: fixed;
 height: 500px;
}
.parallax3{
 width: 100%;
 background: url('rumi-darwaza.jpg') no-repeat center;
 background-size: cover;
 background-attachment: fixed;
 height: 500px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Parallax</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
 </head>
 <body>
  <div class="container">
   <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.
It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="parallax">

  </div>
  <div class="container">
   <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.
It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="parallax2">

  </div>
  <div class="container">
  <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.
It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="parallax3">

  </div>
  <div class="container">
   <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
 Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
 It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.
 It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

I tried setting `position: absolute;` and `left: 0px;` in all the parallax classes but it would make all images come together and the written part gets hidden.
please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
body { margin:0; }
```

should fix your problem

Answer (score 2):

The body tag has a default margin of 8px associated with it. You need to set that margin to 0 using the code in Dirk's answer. Actually, every element has a default margin and padding associated with it. One way to be sure you have total control over the margin and padding of every element is to use the global selector * and set every element's margin and padding equal to 0 at the top of your css file.

```
* {   
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Every HTML element has some DEFAULT margin.
Try to set ALL margins as 0 at first.

```
*{ margin: 0px;}
```

You can also try to set 0 margins just for html or body tags.
Please check CSS Default Values Reference here:

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_default_values.asp